# graphviz: how to prevent clusters from overrinding rank=source statement

Tags: graph, graphviz, rank

[image]

the following code produces the graph above:

```
digraph G {


//---graph config

    fontname=Helvetica

    rankdir = RL
    splines = polyline
    compound = true
    //concentrate = true

    labeljust = c
    labelloc = t

    ranksep=0.5
    nodesep=0.5

    //size="10,10"
    ratio=compress

    edge [
        minlen=1
        arrowsize=0.75
        labeldistance=5     

        fontname=Helvetica
        fontsize=12
        fontcolor=black     

        labelfontsize=12
        labelfontcolor=red
        labelfontname=Helvetica


        ]


    node [
        fontname=Helvetica
        fontsize=12
        fontcolor=black

        regular=true
        shape=diamond
        // width=0.25
        // height=0.25
        ]



// --- # nodes  

{// records
node [shape=record, width=1]


b10 [label="  { R-7 | 5 } | B/10  "]
b20 [label="  { R-6 | 10 } | B/20  "]
b30 [label="  { R-5 | 10 } | B/30  "]
d10 [label="  { R-10 | 15 } | D/10  "]
d20 [label="  { R-9 | 10 } | D/20  "]
d30 [label="  { R-8 | 10 } | D/30  "]
a20 [label="  { R-2 | 5 } | A/20  "]
a30 [label="  { R-1 | 10 } | A/30  "]

}

{// circles
node [shape=circle]
e [label="E"]
c [label="C"]
}

{// box
node [shape=box]
a [label="A"]
}


//--- # edges

{
edge [weight = 1000] 

//straight
c -> b10 -> b20 -> b30
e -> d10 -> d20 -> d30
a20 -> a30 -> a

//combination
{b30 d30} -> a20
}


//--- # Clusters 

// subgraph cluster_1{
// label="a "
// e d10 d20
// }

// subgraph cluster_2{
// label="b "
// c b10 b20 b30
// }

// subgraph cluster_3{
// label="c "
// a30 a20
// }



// --- # bugfixes

{// c before e
edge [style=invis] 
c -> e


{rank=source e c} // force same rank before other nodes
}



}
```

This is exactly as nice and clean as I want it to be. 
However, I want to be able to mark and comment certain sections of the structure and I thouht clusters should be the right means to do that.

If you uncomment the CLUSTERS section of the code you get the following code and respective graph:

```
digraph G {


//---graph config

    fontname=Helvetica

    rankdir = RL
    splines = polyline
    compound = true
    //concentrate = true

    labeljust = c
    labelloc = t

    ranksep=0.5
    nodesep=0.5

    //size="10,10"
    ratio=compress

    edge [
        minlen=1
        arrowsize=0.75
        labeldistance=5     

        fontname=Helvetica
        fontsize=12
        fontcolor=black     

        labelfontsize=12
        labelfontcolor=red
        labelfontname=Helvetica


        ]


    node [
        fontname=Helvetica
        fontsize=12
        fontcolor=black

        regular=true
        shape=diamond
        // width=0.25
        // height=0.25
        ]



// --- # nodes  

{// records
node [shape=record, width=1]


b10 [label="  { R-7 | 5 } | B/10  "]
b20 [label="  { R-6 | 10 } | B/20  "]
b30 [label="  { R-5 | 10 } | B/30  "]
d10 [label="  { R-10 | 15 } | D/10  "]
d20 [label="  { R-9 | 10 } | D/20  "]
d30 [label="  { R-8 | 10 } | D/30  "]
a20 [label="  { R-2 | 5 } | A/20  "]
a30 [label="  { R-1 | 10 } | A/30  "]

}

{// circles
node [shape=circle]
e [label="E"]
c [label="C"]
}

{// box
node [shape=box]
a [label="A"]
}


//--- # edges

{
edge [weight = 1000] 

//straight
c -> b10 -> b20 -> b30
e -> d10 -> d20 -> d30
a20 -> a30 -> a

//combination
{b30 d30} -> a20
}


//--- # Clusters 

subgraph cluster_1{
label="a "
e d10 d20
}

subgraph cluster_2{
label="b "
c b10 b20 b30
}

subgraph cluster_3{
label="c "
a30 a20
}



// --- # bugfixes

{// c before e
edge [style=invis] 
c -> e


{rank=source e c} // force same rank before other nodes
}



}
```

[image]

As you can see from the bugfixes section at the end of the code I want nodes C and E definitely to appear with the same rank 'above' all other nodes.

Furhtermore, I want the upper and lower sequence of records to be connected with nice straight lines like in the first example. The weight of the edges that I introduced does not help.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem and how to make graphviz produce a nice clean graph as in example #1 with just 3 embracing boxes and respective labels added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to only modify what was needed:

- Added an additional cluster without label and `style=invis` (for d30)
- Changed the order of the nodes to have cluster b above cluster a
- Edge weigth removed
- Bugfixes section removed
- Some linebreaks removed

Here's what I get with a recent graphviz version (2.29):

[image]

Not perfect, but a lot closer.

```
digraph G {
//---graph config

    fontname=Helvetica

    rankdir = RL
    splines = polyline
    compound = true
    //concentrate = true

    labeljust = c
    labelloc = t

    ranksep=0.5
    nodesep=0.5

    //size="10,10"
    ratio=compress

    edge [
        minlen=1
        arrowsize=0.75
        labeldistance=5     

        fontname=Helvetica
        fontsize=12
        fontcolor=black     

        labelfontsize=12
        labelfontcolor=red
        labelfontname=Helvetica
        ]

    node [
        fontname=Helvetica
        fontsize=12
        fontcolor=black

        regular=true
        shape=diamond
        // width=0.25
        // height=0.25
        ]

// --- # nodes  

{// records
node [shape=record, width=1]

d10 [label="  { R-10 | 15 } | D/10  "]
d20 [label="  { R-9 | 10 } | D/20  "]
d30 [label="  { R-8 | 10 } | D/30  "]
b10 [label="  { R-7 | 5 } | B/10  "]
b20 [label="  { R-6 | 10 } | B/20  "]
b30 [label="  { R-5 | 10 } | B/30  "]
a20 [label="  { R-2 | 5 } | A/20  "]
a30 [label="  { R-1 | 10 } | A/30  "]
}

{// circles
node [shape=circle]
e [label="E"]
c [label="C"]
}

{// box
node [shape=box]
a [label="A"]
}

//--- # edges

{

//straight
c -> b10 -> b20 -> b30
e -> d10 -> d20 -> d30
a20 -> a30 -> a

//combination
{b30 d30} -> a20}

//--- # Clusters 


 subgraph cluster_1{
 label="a "
 e d10 d20
 }

 subgraph cluster_2{
 label="b "
 c b10 b20 b30
 }

 subgraph cluster_3{
 label="c "
 a30 a20
 }

 subgraph cluster_4{
 label=""
 style=invis
 d30
 }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for. Perfect for me! Thanks! I'll have a close look at your fixes. Great!

Comment: Is there a certain rule which tells me why I have do define  the D-Nodes before the others although I want them to appear at the bottom of the graph? Or did you simply shuffle definitions until it worked?

Comment: Usually nodes on the same rank appear in the order they were defined except if the layout needs to be optimized. Play with `digraph{a;b->{c;d;};e;}`: remove e, a is placed left; remove a, e is placed right; switch order of c and d and they switch places. When you change rankdir, everything changes following rankdir. More complex graphs are often impossible to predict, and then there is the one or the other bug and limitation when using some options or shapes (record). So it's not simply shuffling around the nodes, but I always need visual confirmation to be sure ;-)